# DialogFragment and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any possibility to intercept the key button in `DialogFragment`? sorry for the naive question.. the `onBackPressed` of my `FragmentActivity` is never called.

thanks in advance

```
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ShowPicDialog newFragment = ShowPicDialog.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment prev = manager.findFragmentByTag("picDialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }

            ft.addToBackStack("picDialog");
            newFragment.getArguments().putString("path", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            newFragment.show(ft, "picDialog");
        }
```

sorry I added the snip of code I use to show the dialog.

Comment: Are you using the compatibility library, or testing on a Honeycomb device/emulator?

Comment: I updated my answer with more information. In short, when you create a dialog, it creates a new Activity, so the FragmentActivity is no longer receiving the key events. You need to set up your Dialog in the DialogFragment so that it handles the back key for you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure what the issue is, since you haven't posted any code. But my first guess is that you haven't added the DialogFragment to the back stack by calling the `addToBackStack` method of the `FragmentTransaction` that you're using to add your fragment to the activity.

There are examples right in the Android documentation pages that give examples of a  [good pattern for using a DialogFragment in your Activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentDialog.html).

Since you are displaying a Dialog, the created Dialog will receive the key events, not the parent Activity. So, set a `Dialog.OnKeyListener` when you create the Dialog's fragment, and call `setCancelable(false)` on the `Dialog` to prevent the back key from dismissing it. You can then handle the back key in your `OnKeyListener`'s `onkey` method.

Comment: Did you mean `setCancelable` instead of `isCancelable`?

Answer (score 14):

Best way to Handle DialogFragment with back button:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // On backpress, do your stuff here.
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Rahul Pundhir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915109/1650674) works great if you aren't using the builder pattern. If you are using the Builder pattern on your dialog you can instead do this:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(...)
                .setPositiveButton(...)
                .setNegativeButton(...)
                .setMessage(...)
                .create();

        alertDialog.setOnKeyListener((dialog, keyCode, event) -> {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // TODO do the "back pressed" work here
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        return alertDialog;
    }
```

This works by mimicking how the system calls `onBackPressed()` in the first place (ignoring the tracking and listening for ACTION_UP). See [the source on Dialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java#607)

Answer (score 2):

you can use it for Dialog/ComponentDialog and BottomSheetDialog,
just change the casted dialog with your type of dialog

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
       return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).also { dialog ->
        //change the ComponentDialog with your type of dialog
        (dialog as ComponentDialog).onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : 
            OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                // your code
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution helped me