# DialogFragment now showing when enabling cancelable or keylistener for back button

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

I have a `DialogFragment` (support v4 library), to which I would like to add the possibility to dismiss it by pressing the back button.

Below code displays the dialog fine, but as soon as I activate/comment in the line

```
frag.getDialog().setCancelable(true);
```

in my `newInstance` method, the dialog won't show at all anymore.
Alternatively, I also tried to add a `OnKeyListener` to the dialog (`frag.getDialog()`), which leads to the same result - the dialog not showing at all anymore.

```
public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = ProgressDialogFragment.class.getName();

    private static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String description) {
        final ProgressDialogFragment frag = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        // frag.getDialog().setCancelable(true);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("description", description);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
        }
    }

    public static void display(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, String title, String description) {     
        FragmentTransaction ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(newInstance(title, description), TAG);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    ....
}
```

Related questions, which didn't help though:

- [DialogFragment and back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622031/dialogfragment-and-back-button)
- [Android - Back button and fragment backstack not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610063/android-back-button-and-fragment-backstack-not-working?rq=1)